# How to store the classes in the respective folders in Windows application?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a folder in my project to manage the code 
But there seems to be a problem:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1.Deepak.Connect
{
    class Clas1
    {
    }
}
```

But I don't find any folder in the main folder(`WindowsFormsApplication1`)
that I want to make So, what is the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, Click **show all files** icon in solution explorer. Right click the folder and Click **Include in Project**